# Android: unable to instaniate activity component info error after installing maven in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

After I installed maven in eclipse (m2e plugin) and added mockito dependancy, every project I make and convert to maven (even new ones) compiles but crashes immediatly when running on my device. 
The runtime error I got: Unable to instaniate activity component info, classNotFound exception for main activity. consol says: Could not find appcompat_v7.apk!

I want to fix one of my older projects, which uses appcompat_v7.

the manifest should be ok since the project worked before installing Maven. I believe it did some changes to the build path. How can I fix this?

my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-    4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ProjectName</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
 </build>
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
<version>1.9.5</version>
```

Comment: This question needs more information: what do you mean "maven in eclipse"? What does your POM look like? Are you getting any other errors in your workspace?

Comment: I edited and added to POM. I got no errors in the workspace, only one runtime error that makes the app crash. By "maven in eclipse" I meant I installed the m2e plugin. (Sorry, English is not my native language)

Comment: Is that the full POM? Looks like just a fragment.

Comment: yes.. thats all the content of pom.xml

Comment: Are you sure, that looks invalid? There is no terminating `</dependency>` tag for example.

Comment: Does your build work from the command line? What happens if you install the APK produced by a `mvn package`?